# statement "USE @dbname" doesn't work, why? How to do that?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've got this t-sql snippet:

```
DECLARE @db_name varchar(255);
SET @db_name = 'MY_DATABASE'; -- assuming there is database called 'my_database'
USE @db_name -- this line ends with error "Incorrect syntax near '@db'."
```

But USE with variable (third line of snippet) doesn't work.
**Why it doesn't work?**

Comment: Personally I'd say you have a design issue if you are changing datbase names on the fly in queries (unless you are doing admin work). Why do you want to supply the name of the database dynamically? Maybe if we understood why we could get you a better solutionthan dynamic SQL (Which is to be avoided in production code if all possible for many reasons).

Comment: I just wanted to easily iterate over some set of databases and do some processing (admin related task). 

Kind of this in pseudo code:

DatabaseList = { "DB1", "DB2", "DB3" }
foreach (Database db in DatabaseList)
{
   USE db;
   INSERT INTO table VALUES (value1, value2)
}

Comment: `TSQL` is considered a tool to do the database things, not the meta-database ones. Normally, meta-database tasks (like the one you described) are performed by using an external tool like a `Perl` or `PHP` script which would connect to each database individually and run the query you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot provide the name of the database for `USE` statement in a variable.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Why not? and is there a walk-around?

Answer (score 4):

As you have noticed, the `USE` statement does not accept a variable as parameter. The only alternative that quickly comes to mind is quite crude and extremely error prone, but here you go:

```
EXEC ('USE ' + @db_name + '
       SELECT * FROM some_table
       INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (1)')
```

I hope that someone else can do better :-)

Comment: Also quite prone to SQL injection.  Look that up (as well as the QUOTENAME() function, which can help in a lot cases).

Comment: Indeed it is. Depending on the use case, this might or might not be a problem :)

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server will not accept the `USE` statement with a variable.

To use database names dynamically, you have to create dynamic SQL statements with (almost) fully qualified names as follows:

```
Declare @SQL VarChar (100)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @DatabaseName + '.dbo.TableName'
```

and then you execute it using `sp_SQLExec`

Comment: Just beware of SQL injection as I commented on Jørn's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is with an if statement:

```
if @DBName = 'DB1'
    <query with DB1>
else
    <query with DB2>
```