# In T-SQL can you use a variable with the USE command

Tags: t-sql

I'm working on a SQL script where I need to refer to the database name in multiple stops. This script will be used to run against different databases so I wanted to store the database name in a variable so you only need to change the name in one location in the script.

The main problem I have with this script is with the USE command. So the code looks like.

```
DECLARE @DBName varchar(50)
SET @DBName = '[master]'

USE @DBName
```

SQL doesn't like this. Is there a way to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried "exec('use master')", but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184219/statement-use-dbname-doesnt-work-why-how-to-do-that

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
declare @dbname varchar(250)
declare @Sql varchar(250)

set @dbname='PMDB'

SELECT @Sql ='select * from ' + @dbname + '.dbo.Account'


EXEC(@Sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is not very elegant, but it works just fine

```
if @DBName = 'DB1'
    <query with DB1>
else
    <query with DB2>
```